# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to run this java & mysql program, but when i compile, it is not showing any errors.

But when i run the code, it is showing some exceptions..

What might be the error?

code:Version.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Version
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        String cs = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/google";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(cs, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM user";
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            finally
            {
            try 
            {
            if (st != null) 
            {
            st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
            con.close();
            }
            } catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code, i am getting this error message

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Version
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Version
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: Version.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: are you using command line or any ide like eclipse

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: @SajanChandran I am using command line

Answer (score 3):

The class needs to be declared as `public`

```
public class Version{
   //rest of code
}
```

By default classes are `package-private` as mentioned in Oracles Java Tutorials:

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as
>   package-private), it is visible only within its own package.

When the program attempts to run the `Version` class cannot be found because it is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Classes aren't public by default ?

Comment: @Anime by default classes are package private

Comment: Since there is no package in the code, I don't think access specifier is the problem.

Comment: there is no need for the `class` to be declared `public`, even without `public` the jvm loads the class correctly and works.see link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#CLASS_DEF